# How to inject angular services correctly

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, toastr

I created a service called `notifier` that use `toastr` to alert the user during the log in process if the user successfully logged in or not.

here is my log in module:

```
var login = angular.module('login',[]);

    login.controller('mvLoginCtrl', function($scope, $http){
        $scope.signin = function(username, passowrd){
            $http.post('/login', {username:username, passowrd:passowrd}).then(function(response){
                if(response.data.success){
                    mvNotifier.notify('You have successfully signed in!');
                }else{
                    mvNotifier.notify('Username/Password combination incorrect');
                }
            })
        }
    })
```

i got no errors till here but when i try to sign in i get this obvious error :

> ReferenceError: mvNotifier is not defined

i changed my log in module at the line 2 including the required dependencies:

```
login.controller('mvLoginCtrl', function($scope, $http, mvNotifier)
```

but then i got different error

> Error: [$injector:unpr]
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.20/$injector/unpr?p0=mvIdentityProvider%20%3C-%20mvIdentity

and i want to ask what is the reason i got this error and how to solve it.
here is my mvNotifier module code:

```
var notifier = angular.module('notifier', []);

    notifier.value('mvToastr', toastr);
    notifier.factory('mvNotifier', function(myToastr){
        return{
            notify: function(msg){
                mvToastr.success(msg);
                console.log(msg);
            }
        }
    })
```

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to inject myNotifier something like this:

```
var login = angular.module('login',['notifier']);

    login.controller('mvLoginCtrl', ['$scope','$http','mvNotifier',function($scope, $http,mvNotifier){
        $scope.signin = function(username, passowrd){
            $http.post('/login', {username:username, passowrd:passowrd}).then(function(response){
                if(response.data.success){
                    mvNotifier.notify('You have successfully signed in!');
                }else{
                    mvNotifier.notify('Username/Password combination incorrect');
                }
            })
        }
    }])
```

More on [Dependency Injection](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di)

Comment: Thank you i tired both solutions and still get same error

Comment: Hi I have updated the answer with the correct service name in dependency chain you had named it notifier and I had myNotifier earlier

Comment: i did noticed this and i write it correctly i even changed your solution the function argument  notifier instead of myNotifier but still same error

Comment: I did thank you , but still get the same error here is my app.js maybe it help:
var myapp= angular.module('myapp',['ngResource','ngRoute','main','login']);

myapp.config(function($routeProvider,$locationProvider){
 $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
 $routeProvider
  .when('/',{templateUrl: '/partials/main/main', contorller: 'mvMainCtrl'})
});

Comment: Hello i just wanna add this comment in case anyone had the same problem, the answer up is correct with couple changes on the services names, and i still have the same problem with the notifier service for a reason i still don't know but it works well with the other services

Answer (score 1):

You need to add notifier module as a dependency in login module.

```
var login = angular.module('login',["notifier"]);
```

Then this should work.

```
login.controller('mvLoginCtrl', function($scope, $http, mvNotifier)
```

**Edit:** [DEMO](http://jsbin.com/fuvowaxa/1/edit)

Comment: take a look at the demo.